# Spacing before section is missing when using user defined listings

Tags: spacing, listings, sections-paragraphs

I define a user environment but for some reason, the space before section 3 is missing. Please see the following example. Why this happen? How can I make the spaces the same before section 2 and section 3?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{% 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, 
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    escapeinside = ||,
    breakindent=0pt} 
\lstnewenvironment{Code}{}{}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
test the space
\section{Section 2}
\begin{Code}
    abc
\end{Code}
test the space
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem disappears if there is some paragraph material between the section heading and the code.  One solution is to add `\leavevmode` before the code.  This can be automated by adding the command to the start code of the new listings environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{Code}{\leavevmode}{}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    escapeinside = ||,
    breakindent=0pt}
\lstnewenvironment{Code}{\leavevmode}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
test the space
\section{Section 2}
\begin{Code}
    abc
\end{Code}
test the space

\section{Section 3}
test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! where can I find the document that I can learn more and help others like you do?

Comment: I glad this helps.  As for learnng, be curious, read whatever documentation you can and try answering questions here.